# Spoofing SMS messages

Tags: sms

I received a message recently on a droid phone that appeared to have originated from an Iphone in my contact list.  I was able to look at the Iphone from which the message appeared to have originated and it showed the exact same message as having been sent from that Iphone.  But I don't think the message actually originated on that Iphone.  Is it possible to spoof a message so that the message appears on both the droid phone as a received message and on the Iphone as a sent message simultaneously?

Comment: Anything is *theoretically* possible. What makes you think it wasn't sent from the iPhone, though? Even if it was malware that had infected the iPhone and sent it from the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

The Iphone did indeed send the message, because the Iphone is saying "I sent the message". This is impossible to do remotely unless Iphones have a serious flaw (Very unlikely). However, it is possible that the Iphone is actually compromised by a backdoor, malware, etc. In any case, the Iphone was involved.